# Zero integration for any function in $C_c(X)$ would imply that the measure is zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $X$ be any locally compact Hausdorff space, and $\mu$ be a positive finite regular (both inner and outer) measure on $X$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)$ is compact. We have that
$$\int_X f \ d\mu = 0$$
for each $f\in C_c(X)$.

Then can we conclude that $\mu =0$?

I was trying to find a counter-example, but am stuck at some technical issue.

Comment: Why did you delete the tags @ArcticChar? Both seemed fitting to me.

Comment: @MaoWao is the lebesgue integral really applicable here? This question has nothing to do with lebesgue measure. For real analysis, it is marginal, but I think mixing a measure theory question with the other $\epsilon-\delta$ question on the site does no good.

Comment: @ArcticChar But the integral is certainly a Lebesgue integral. That term is also used if the measure is not the Lebesgue measure. And for real analysis, I think this should really be discussed on meta then. As it stands, the tag info clearly states that real analysis includes (the analytic parts of) measure theory. If one takes the content of courses and textbooks, real analysis is more fitting than functional analysis.

Comment: @ArcticChar In general, tags increase the visibility of questions, so I'm not very fond of deleting them against the will of the OP if they are not clearly misplaced.

Comment: @MaoWao That's not always true though. Tag is also used to filter unwanted information (one can "ignore" the tag). For example I ignore all questions with "analysis" tag since there is too much noise there. There's a similar meta discussion [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30828/trying-to-add-the-abstract-algebra-tag)

Comment: May be we can discuss the matter in [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging) chat room, @MaoWao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you may.

Note that $I_\mu : C_0(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $I_\mu (f) = \int_X f d\mu$ is a continuous linear functional. Since $C_c(X)$ is dense in $C_0(X)$ and $I_\mu$ is zero on a dense set, it must extend uniquely to the zero functional on space $C_0(X)$. But the zero functional is represented by integration against the zero measure, so $\mu = 0$.

Comment: You use the fact that the measure representing $I_\mu$ is unique, but this is not much easier to prove than the statement from the question.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer uses implicitly the Markov-Riesz theorem, but one can also argue directly (in particular, this statement could be used in the proof of the Markov-Riesz theorem).

Let $K\subset X$ be compact. By Urysohn's lemma there exists a function $f\in C_c(X)$ such that $0\leq f\leq 1$ and $f|_K=1$. Thus
$$
0\leq\mu(K)=\int_X1_K\,d\mu\leq \int_X f\,d\mu=0
$$
and hence $\mu(K)=0$.

For arbitrary measurable $A\subset K$ the inner regularity of $\mu$ implies
$$
\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(K)\mid K\subset A\text{ compact}\}=0.
$$
Note that neither finiteness nor outer regularity of $\mu$ are needed.

Comment: Thank you, @MaoWao , but will this method work if $\mu$ is a complex (hence finite) radon measure? If we use the Markov-Riesz Theorem, then one can drop the positivity property of $\mu$ and the conclusion still holds true. Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @CarlButcher Not directly, no. But you can invoke the Hahn decomposition of the positive and negative part of $\mu$ and then apply the same argument. And as I mentioned in my comment to the other answer, the uniqueness part in the Markov-Riesz theorem you use here is essentially what you want to prove, so using it here seems circular to me.